# $ inside curly brackets

Tags: javascript

I am going through a tutorial, and the author has written a line of code in a GET response through a query string. They write the $ inside the curly brackets without any backticks.

Here is the line of code:

```
Product.find({ '_id':{$in:items}}).exec({err,docs}=>{ return res.status(200).send(docs) })
```

I have no idea what exactly is happening.

Comment: `$in` is just a property name. So, there is an object, one of the properties is called literally "dollar-in" and the value is that `items` variable. That object is assigned to the `_id` property of another one.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in

Comment: Inside tick marks `$` indicates a template.  In this usage, it's the start of an identifier.  Identifiers in JS must start with `$`, `_`, or any unicode "letter" character.  `ಠ_ಠ` is a valid identifier in JS.

Comment: @Amy, "`ಠ_ಠ`" > glad to see someone else shares my variable naming conventions.

Comment: @junvar It's the perfect name for a function that throws an exception.  `ಠ_ಠ("this shouldn't be happening");`  Then you get the look of disapproval in your console's stack trace on errors.

Answer (score 2):

`$` is a valid character in variable names.
E.g.

```
let x = 5;
let $ = 6;
let x$8_$$ = 7;
let obj = {$: 8, $$$__$sf93$: 9};
```

In your snippet, they're using `$in` as the key in an object literal.
I.e., let's say `items = [1,2,3]`, then the param to `Product.find` is `{'_id': {'$in': [1, 2, 3]}}`.